# compound noun versus direct address

Tags: nouns, forms-of-address

If I said the following words, "I will watch a movie today only if I take care of the dust devil."

How can the listener know that I am saying "dust devil" versus addressing the pronoun "devil"?

If there was no pause between dust and devil I assume that I am not addressing the pronoun of the word "devil".

Another example, "I will go to college only if I do chemistry devil." In this case, because the speaker was not looking at the sky nor having a pause before the word "devil", "chemistry devil" becomes the compound noun.

Comment: Vocatives are distinguished in speech -- which is the only place they are used -- by intonation and rhythm. Written descriptions of dialog do the best they can with commas and dashes and whatnot, but it's still true that any written sentence is multiply ambiguous because it can't represent the way the sentence is actually pronounced.

Comment: nice, thank you. I see, in writing it can still be ambiguous. For example, I want to date him, Michael. Am I saying that I want to date Micheal? Or am I talking to someone named Michael?

Comment: Context answers most questions like these. If you're talking to Michael, he will know that. If you're talking about someone named Michael, your listener will know that, too. And if you are addicted to the hypothetical idea of addressing Michael about a Michael you want to date, you would say *that man Michael, sorry not you*.